# Gradle DSL Method not found: 'multiDexEnabled'; using gradle that does not contain the method

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

This question has been asked before, however, I have followed the directions carefully and am still receiving this issue. I need some help with figuring out what I am missing with my particular situation. Here is what I have done.

1) Add android-support-multidex.jar: Added android-support-multidex.jar to projected libs folder
2) Edit project build.gradle: I modified my build.gradle file located in my project's folder.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    .....
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

3) Modify Project Application class: I have a class that extends Application. I added the following to it.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

This was originally an Eclipse project. I exported the Eclipse project, and then imported the build.gradle file in Android Studio. I have not been able to successfully run the project since. Any help with steps I have missed would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the contents of my top-level build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have another `build.gradle` file, in your project's root directory (this one probably came from your `app/` directory). If you could edit your question and paste in the top-level `build.gradle` file, that would help us confirm the source of your difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

as multidex support was not offered in that 7-month-old beta release of the Gradle for Android plugin.