# Finished with non-zero exit value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I get this error when I try to run the app

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dusanp.passer"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-   android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.7.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: Remove all the parse-*.jar files from your libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX file, known as a multidex configuration

This might be due to exceeding the 65K methods dex limit imposed by Android. This problem can be solved either by cleaning the project, and removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build.gradle, or by adding multidex support.

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

1. Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex
2. Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class

Here is the complete details: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Thanks. But now, after I enabled multidex, I get this error :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

Comment: Follow this link might help you: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android/issues/80

Comment: I am not sure where to put  exclude module: 'bolts-android'}
when I put it under compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
 I get Error:(36, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Passer' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: which version of Gradle plugin are you using? Try to update with the latest stable version. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932066/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-multidexenabled-using-gradle-that-does-not-conta

Comment: The gradle version is 1.5.0

Comment: @RohitSharma The duplicate entry exception is somenthing different from 65536 methods limit.